# Physical interpretation of operator-sum measurement of state after measuring

Tags: quantum-computation, quantum-information

On page 362 of [Nielsen & Chuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information), in the attached reference, why do we have

$$|e_k\rangle \langle e_k|U(P \oplus |e_0\rangle \langle e_0|)U^{\dagger} |e_k\rangle \langle e_k|$$

instead of

$$|e_k\rangle \langle e_k|U(P \oplus |e_0\rangle \langle e_0|)U^{\dagger} (|e_k\rangle \langle e_k|)^{\dagger} \ \  ?$$

They are trying there to give a physical interpretation of the operator sum representation.

I thought for getting the state after measurement we must do $M_m * $ operator $M_m$ normalized?

---

[image: Nielsen and Chuang page 362 physical interpretation of operator-sum representation]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121 in that regard.

Comment: Also, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: I have attempted to correct your formulas. Please check them.

Comment: Please transcribe the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the projector onto a pure state is self-adjoint${}^{(1)}$, i.e. $(|e_k\rangle\langle e_k|)^\dagger=|e_k\rangle\langle e_k|$ so the two expressions from your post are the same.

---

${}^{(1)}$ This comes from the identity
$(|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)^\dagger=|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|$ for the [Hermitian adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) which holds due to
\begin{align*}
\big\langle x,\color{red}{(|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)^\dagger} y\big\rangle\overset{\text{Def.}}=\big\langle (|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)x,y\big\rangle&=\big\langle \langle\phi,x\rangle\psi,y\big\rangle\\
&=\langle x,\phi\rangle\langle\psi,y\rangle\\
&=\big\langle x,\langle\psi,y\rangle\phi\big\rangle=\big\langle x,\color{red}{(|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|)}y\big\rangle\,.
\end{align*}